# FizzBuzz using JDK8 Lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8, fizzbuzz

Just want to see by JDK8 lambda how small the program can be, my approach is using a result builder:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0 , 100).forEach(i ->{
        StringBuffer bfr= new StringBuffer();
        if(i % 3 == 0 )
            bfr.append("Fizz");
        if(i % 5 == 0 )
            bfr.append("Buzz");
        if(i % 3 != 0 && i % 5 != 0 )
            bfr.append(i);

        System.out.println(bfr.toString());
});
```

Can anyone try to use predicate instead ? I could not think of a way to do this.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/stuart-marks/9657079

Comment: @StuartMarks hats off to you !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are three solutions.

Java 8 with Streams:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100).mapToObj(
        i -> i % 3 == 0 ?
                (i % 5 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz" : "Fizz") :
                (i % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : i))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Java 8 with [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/):

```
IntInterval.zeroTo(100).collect(
        i -> i % 3 == 0 ?
                (i % 5 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz" : "Fizz") :
                (i % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : i))
        .each(System.out::println);
```

Java 8 with Eclipse Collections using Predicates:

```
Interval.zeroTo(100).collect(
        new CaseFunction<Integer, String>(Object::toString)
            .addCase(i -> i % 15 == 0, e -> "FizzBuzz")
            .addCase(i -> i % 3 == 0, e -> "Fizz")
            .addCase(i -> i % 5 == 0, e -> "Buzz"))
        .each(System.out::println);
```

**Update**:

As of the Eclipse Collections [8.0 release](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/releases/tag/8.0.0), the functional interfaces in Eclipse Collections now extend the equivalent functional interfaces in Java 8.  This means that `CaseFunction` can now be used as a `java.util.function.Function`, which means it will work with `Stream.map(Function)`.  The following example uses `CaseFunction` with a `Stream<Integer>`:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100).boxed().map(
        new CaseFunction<Integer, String>(Object::toString)
                .addCase(i -> i % 15 == 0, e -> "FizzBuzz")
                .addCase(i -> i % 3 == 0, e -> "Fizz")
                .addCase(i -> i % 5 == 0, e -> "Buzz"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Update:**

As of the Eclipse Collections [8.1 release](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections/releases/tag/8.1.0), there is now support for primitive case functions.  The code above can now be written as follows, removing the call to `boxed`.  `IntCaseFunction` implements `IntToObjectFunction` which extends `java.util.function.IntFunction`.

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100).mapToObj(
        new IntCaseFunction<>(Integer::toString)
                .addCase(i -> i % 15 == 0, e -> "FizzBuzz")
                .addCase(i -> i % 3 == 0, e -> "Fizz")
                .addCase(i -> i % 5 == 0, e -> "Buzz"))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

`IntCaseFunction` will also work with the `IntInterval` example, passed as the parameter to the `collect` method.

**Note:** I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections).

Comment: Nice , thanks ! Need to brush up more on the Stream api

Answer (score 2):

My version using format.

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).forEach(
    i -> System.out.format("%s%s%n",
                           (i % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz": ""),
                           (i % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz": (i % 3 == 0 ? "" : i))
         )
);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100).forEach(FizzBuzz::check);
    }

    public static void check(int n) {
        System.out.println((n % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" : "") + (n % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : ""));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I was watching Kevlin Henney who was fizzbuzzing different languages on one of his talk. It got me thinking about Java 8 and none of the provided solutions were elegant for me. It is very hard to read chained ternary operators. This is what I came up with:

```
public class MyApproach {
    private java.util.function.IntPredicate divBy(int number) {
        return i -> i % number == 0;
    }

    public String fizzBuzz(int number) {
        String result = "";
        result += divBy(3).test(number) ? "Fizz" : "";
        result += divBy(5).test(number) ? "Buzz" : "";
        return (result).isEmpty() ? String.valueOf(number) : result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyApproach myApproach = new MyApproach();
        int startInclusive = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int endInclusive = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);

        IntStream.rangeClosed(startInclusive, endInclusive)
            .mapToObj(myApproach::fizzBuzz)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This way we can throw in some test:

```
class FizzBuzzTest extends Specification {
    def "parametrized test for fizzBuzz method" () {
        given:
        def myApproach = new MyApproach()

        expect:
        result == myApproach.fizzBuzz(num)

        where:
        result     | num
        "Fizz"     | 21
        "Fizz"     | 123
        "Buzz"     | 50
        "Buzz"     | 250
        "FizzBuzz" | 150
        "13"       | 13
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Version with infinite streams. Origin from Haskell. Often shown in a Kevlin Henney Presentation

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // creates an infinite stream with "Fizz" on every 3rd position
    Stream<String> fizzes = Stream.generate(() -> new String[] {"","","Fizz"}).flatMap(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr));
    // creates an infinite stream with "Buzz" on every 5th position 
    Iterator<String> buzzes = Stream.generate(() -> new String[] {"","","","","Buzz"}).flatMap(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr)).iterator();
    // Infinite number stream as String
    Iterator<String> integers = IntStream.iterate(1, x -> x + 1).mapToObj(value -> Integer.valueOf(value).toString()).iterator();

    // concatenates fizzes with buzzes and return the max string from number or the concatenation
    // FizzBuzz > Fizz > Buzz > 'any number as string' > ""
    String[] array = fizzes.limit(100).map(fizz -> max(integers.next(), fizz+buzzes.next())).toArray(value -> new String[value]);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
}

public static String max(String val1, String val2) {
    return val1.compareTo(val2) >= 0 ? val1 : val2;
}
```

Little more accurate:

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // creates an infinite stream with "Fizz" on every 3rd position
        Stream<String> fizzes = Stream.generate(() -> new String[] {"","","Fizz"}).flatMap(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr));
        // creates an infinite stream with "Buzz" on every 5th position
        Iterator<String> buzzes = Stream.generate(() -> new String[] {"","","","","Buzz"}).flatMap(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr)).iterator();
        // Concatenates fizzes with buzzes
        Iterator<String> words = fizzes.map(fizz -> fizz+buzzes.next()).iterator();
        // Infinite number stream as String
        Stream<String> numbers = IntStream.iterate(1, x -> x + 1).mapToObj(Integer::toString);
        // Choice operation word or number
        BinaryOperator<String> choice1 = FizzBuzz::max;
        BinaryOperator<String> choice2 = FizzBuzz::emptyAsNumberOrWord;

        numbers.limit(100).map(number -> choice1.apply(number, words.next())).forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    public static String max(String number, String word) {
        return number.compareTo(word) >= 0 ? number : word;
    }

    public static String emptyAsNumberOrWord(String number, String word) {
        return word.isEmpty() ? number : word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be rewritten with predicates in a such way:

```
        IntPredicate dividesBy3 = i -> i % 3 == 0;
        IntPredicate dividesBy5 = i -> i % 5 == 0;
        IntPredicate doesntDivide = dividesBy3.negate().and(dividesBy5.negate());

        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100).forEach(i -> {
            StringBuffer bfr = new StringBuffer();

            if (dividesBy3.test(i)) bfr.append("Fizz");
            if (dividesBy5.test(i)) bfr.append("Buzz");
            if (doesntDivide.test(i)) bfr.append(i);

            System.out.println(bfr);
    });
```

But actually is doesn't become smaller :)

Comment: dividesBy3.negate().and(dividesBy5.negate());

You can rewrite this as;
dividesBy3.or(dividesBy5).negate();

Answer (score 0):

> Stream API implementation:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class FizzBuzz {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String FIZZ = "Fizz";
        final String BUZZ = "Buzz";
        Stream.iterate(1, n -> n + 1)
                .limit(100)
                .forEachOrdered(item -> {
                    if (item % 3 == 0 && item % 5 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(FIZZ + " " + BUZZ);
                        return;
                    } else if (item % 3 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(FIZZ);
                        return;
                    } else if (item % 5 == 0) {
                        System.out.println(BUZZ);
                        return;
                    }

                    System.out.println(item);
                });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
      .mapToObj(x -> x % 15 == 0 ? "FizzBuzz" : x % 5 == 0 ? "Buzz" : x % 3 == 0 ? "Fizz" : x)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    private static final int RANGE_START = 1;
    private static final int RANGE_END = 100;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(RANGE_START, RANGE_END)
                .mapToObj(FizzBuzz::FizzBuzzMapper)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static String FizzBuzzMapper(final int number) {
        return PAIR_LIST.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.getKey().test(number))
                .map(Pair::getValue)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(String.valueOf(number));
    }

    private static final List<Pair<Predicate<Integer>, String>> PAIR_LIST = List.of(
            Pair.of(i -> integerPredicate(15).test(i), "FizzBuzz"),
            Pair.of(i -> integerPredicate(5).test(i), "Buzz"),
            Pair.of(i -> integerPredicate(3).test(i), "Fizz")
    );

    private static Predicate<Integer> integerPredicate(final int divisor) {
        return i -> i % divisor == 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My functional approach version, admittedly not very short.

It's neither using else, nor the ternary operator. But it is extendable by adding new conditions to the fizzBuzzers map.

```
public class FizzBuzz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Map<Integer, String> fizzBuzzers = new HashMap<>();
        fizzBuzzers.put(3,  "Fizz");
        fizzBuzzers.put(5,  "Buzz");
        fizzBuzzers.put(8,  "Bingo");
        fizzBuzzers.put(17, "Dingo");
        
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 100)
            .forEach(i -> System.out.println(fizzBuzz(i, fizzBuzzers)));

    }

    private static String fizzBuzz(int i, Map<Integer, String> fizzBuzzers) {
        final List<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> multiBuzz = fizzBuzzers.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(entry -> i % entry.getKey() == 0)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        
        if (!multiBuzz.isEmpty()) {
            return multiBuzz.stream()
                    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining());
        }
        return String.valueOf(i);
    }
```